# How to Restrict INSERT operations on table for DB2?

Tags: permissions, db2, db2-luw

I have a table OAUTH20_TOKEN_CACHE for which I have restricted INSERT operations by running below command.
db2 REVOKE INSERT ON HVD121.OAUTH20_TOKEN_CACHE FROM USER HVD121

This could be seen
INSERTAUTH = 'N' for particular grantee 'HVD121' in the 'SYSTABAUTH' table,but still I could see INSERT operations succeeding for the particular table wherein the connection is established using user 'HVD121.

Is this correct approach??

Comment: @mustaccio DB2 version 10.5.4 on RHEL 6.5

Answer (score 2):

User in DB2 can have privileges granted via user's groups and roles as well. 
DB2 stores permissions on objects, not restrictions. You can't revoke a privilege on an object from a user, if this user hasn't been granted this permission explicitly (you get `SQL0556N` on such a revoke statement). The reason you see `INSERTAUTH = 'N'` in SYSCAT.TABAUTH (SYSIBM.SYSTABAUTH) is that this user has some other `*AUTH` permission(s) on this table, but not INSERT.

So, you can't revoke a privilege from a user explicitly, if this user has this privilege via its groups or roles (we don't consider LBAC here).

2 checks should be done to understand why some particular user has some privilege on some object.
Change the constants `'MYUSER'`, `'MYSCHEMA'`, `'MYTABLE'` below accordingly.

1) If the user has DATAACCESS database authority:

```
SELECT P.GRANTEE, P.GRANTEETYPE
FROM SYSCAT.DBAUTH P
CROSS JOIN TABLE(VALUES 'MYUSER') A (AUTHID)
JOIN TABLE (
SELECT GROUP, 'G' FROM table(AUTH_LIST_GROUPS_FOR_AUTHID(A.AUTHID))
  UNION ALL
select ROLENAME, 'R' from table(AUTH_LIST_ROLES_FOR_AUTHID(A.AUTHID, 'U'))
  UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM TABLE(VALUES ('PUBLIC', 'G'), (A.AUTHID, 'U')) T (AUTHID, AUTHIDTYPE)
) U (AUTHID, AUTHIDTYPE) ON U.AUTHID=P.GRANTEE AND U.AUTHIDTYPE=P.GRANTEETYPE
WHERE P.DATAACCESSAUTH='Y';
```

2) If the user has the privilege on the table:

```
SELECT  
  P.PRIVILEGE, P.OBJECTTYPE, P.OBJECTSCHEMA, P.OBJECTNAME
, U.AUTHID, U.AUTHIDTYPE
FROM SYSIBMADM.PRIVILEGES P
CROSS JOIN TABLE(VALUES 'MYUSER') A (AUTHID)
JOIN TABLE (
SELECT GROUP, 'G' FROM table(AUTH_LIST_GROUPS_FOR_AUTHID(A.AUTHID))
  UNION ALL
select ROLENAME, 'R' from table(AUTH_LIST_ROLES_FOR_AUTHID(A.AUTHID, 'U'))
  UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM TABLE(VALUES ('PUBLIC', 'G'), (A.AUTHID, 'U')) T (AUTHID, AUTHIDTYPE)
) U (AUTHID, AUTHIDTYPE) ON U.AUTHID=P.AUTHID AND U.AUTHIDTYPE=P.AUTHIDTYPE
WHERE P.OBJECTSCHEMA = 'MYSCHEMA' AND P.OBJECTNAME='MYTABLE' AND P.OBJECTTYPE='TABLE'
AND P.PRIVILEGE IN ('INSERT', 'CONTROL')
ORDER BY 2, 3, 4;
```

@Redhat: Show the results of the queries above for `MYSCHEMA=HVD121, MYTABLE=OAUTH20_TOKEN_CACHE, MYUSER=HVD121`.